# Fetch post method is not working - react native

Tags: react-native

I've a strange issue. Here the 1st method doesn't work. Here it gives error on the key username. It gives username is required error. However the 2nd method works.  Both are basically the same. What might be the problem here

P.S the api in server is simple sql. I've not used multipart upload in the code.

1st function

```
test = () => {
 fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', //putting multipart/form-data doesn't work as well
  },
   body: JSON.stringify({
     username: 'abc',
   }),
 })
 .then((response) => console.log('fetchResponse', response))
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error('fetchError', error);
 });
}
```

2nd function

```
test = () => {
 let data = new FormData();
 data.append("username", "abc");

 fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
   body: data,
 })
 .then((response) => console.log('fetchResponse', response))
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error('fetchError', error);
 });
}
```

Server Side code:

Controller

```
public function index_post(){
    $username = $this->post('username', TRUE, TRUE);


    $password = $this->post('password', TRUE, TRUE);

    $push_key = $this->post('push_key');

    $user = $this->login->checklogin($username, $password);

    if ($user['status']) {

        if(!$user['customer']->model_image){
            $user['customer']->model_image='';
        }
        if(!$user['customer']->car_image){
            $user['customer']->car_image='';
        }
        return $this->responsedata($user['customer']);
    } else {
        return $this->responseerror($user['msg']);
    }

}
```

Model

```
public function checkLogin($username, $password){
    $where= "((`password` ='".md5($password)."') or (`p_reset_code` = '".$password."'))";
    $data = array();
    $username = str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($username));
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where($where);

    $user = $this->db->get('tbl_appusers');

    if ($user->num_rows() > 0) {
        if (!$user->row()->is_logged_in) {
            if($password == $user->row()->p_reset_code){

                            if($user->row()->p_reset_date == date('Y-m-d')){
                                $no= strval($user->row()->p_reset_no);
                            }else{
                                $no = '0';
                            }
                            $newpassword=$user->row()->temp_password;
                        $arr=array('is_logged_in'=>0,
                                'p_reset_code'=>'',
                                 'p_reset_no'=>$no,
                                'temp_password'=>'',
                                'password'=>$newpassword
                            );

                        sendmail_password_reset_success($user->row()->email);

                        }else{
                            $arr= array('is_logged_in'=>0);
                        }
            $this->db->where('customer_id', $user->row()->customer_id)->update('tbl_appusers', $arr);
            $customer = $this->db
                ->select('tbl_customers.customer_id,tbl_customers.email, tbl_customers.salesdate, tbl_customers.name, tbl_customers.address, tbl_customers.cellphone, tbl_customers.scheme, tbl_customers.vcn, tbl_customers.ven, tbl_customers.model, tbl_customers.varient, tbl_customers.vehicleid, tbl_customers.color, tbl_customers.registrationno,tbl_customers.profile_image')
                tbl_customers.scheme, tbl_customers.vcn, tbl_customers.ven, tbl_customers.vehicleid,tbl_customers.model, tbl_customers.varient, tbl_customers.color, tbl_customers.registrationno,tbl_customers.profile_image')
                ->join('tbl_appusers', 'tbl_appusers.customer_id=tbl_customers.customer_id')
                ->join('tbl_model_images', 'tbl_model_images.model=tbl_customers.model', LEFT)
                ->where('tbl_customers.customer_id', $user->row()->customer_id)
                ->get('tbl_customers')->row();


                $this->db = $this->load->database('db2', true);
                $arra=array('vehicleid'=>$customer->vehicleid);
                $this->db->select('model_image, car_image')->from('mtable_vehicles')->where($arra);

                $vehicles = $this->db->get()->row();

                $customer->model_image=@$vehicles->model_image;
                $customer->car_image=@$vehicles->car_image;

            $data['status'] = true;
            if(!$customer->profile_image){$customer->profile_image='';}
            $data['customer'] = $customer;
        } else {
            $data['status'] = false;
            $data['msg'] = "Already logged in";
        }
    } else {
        $data['status'] = false;
        $data['msg'] = "username and password does not match in our system please try again";
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I'm getting the following response in console

```
fetchResponse

{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: undefined, headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config
:
{transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", adapter: ƒ, …}
data
:
{status: false, data: "username is required"}
headers
:
{transfer-encoding: "chunked", connection: "Keep-Alive", content-type: "application/json", set-cookie: Array(1), server: "Apache", …}
request
:
XMLHttpRequest {UNSENT: 0, OPENED: 1, HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2, LOADING: 3, DONE: 4, …}
status
:
200
statusText
:
undefined
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: I guess it is how you handle the data on the backend. Both should work with the correct backend implementation. Can you provide your backend implementation too ?

Comment: did you get error on server side or client side?

Comment: @oma the server side is coded in Code Igniter. I've little knowledge on CI. Please see the server side code above.

Comment: @MohamedSameer the error is in client side. If I test the api, it works fine. Though I noticed if I put space in front or at the back of the key 'username', it gives the same error while testing.

Comment: @AmritaStha - what is the error you are getting? what status code are you getting back?

Comment: this is what I'm getting in response data
:
{status: false, data: "username is required"} and in 2nd method the status is true

Comment: @AmritaStha - gave a possible thing to try in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I am no CodeIgniter expert either, but since the request looks good IMO, I was wondering if the backend tries to access the variables in the right way.

Looking at the CI documentation, `$this->input->post(....` would be the correct call instead of `$this->post(...`.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::post

Could this be the reason why the backend doesn't detect the username?

In general I would advise debugging the backend with breakpoints making sure all expected data arrives and you process it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had a similar problem with a PHP API I was interacting with.

I know this sounds alittle crazy, but could you try this:

```
test = () => {
 fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', //putting multipart/form-data doesn't work as well
  },
   body: "?username=abc"
 })
 .then((response) => console.log('fetchResponse', response))
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error('fetchError', error);
 });
}
```

You should be able to see if your API then accepts this.

Comment: Have you only changed - body: "?username=abc". What does that mean?